# module.export is not exporting returned variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two files, one file(intsaKey.js) i am creating a function that would create a key. Am trying to export the function using modules.export.

```
//instaKey.js    
const Request = require("request");

module.exports = {
instaKey: () => {

    let applicationToken;

    headers = {};
    headers["client-id"] = clientId;
    headers["client-secret"] = clientSecret;
    headers["Accept-Language"] = "en_US";
    headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    Request.post({
            headers: headers,
            url: `${BaseUrl}/oauth2/token/`,
            formData: {
                grant_type: `client_credentials`,
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret
            },
        },
        (error, instaApplicationTokenResponse, instaApplicationTokenResBody) => {
            if (instaApplicationTokenResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Authentication api is success");
                applicationToken = JSON.parse(instamojoApplicationTokenResBody).access_token;
                console.log(applicationToken);
                return applicationToken;
            }
        });
},
```

}

In another file(payment.js), I am trying to get the key. So console.log inside instaKey.js is getting printed but the key itself is not getting printed or returned.

```
//payment.js
const {
instaKey
} = require("./insta");

module.exports = {

createOrder: (req, res) => {

    console.log("Key is ");
    let key = instaKey().applicationToken;
    console.log(key); //undefined :( How do I get the key here ?
    console.log(instaKey()); //
            //below gets printed 
            //Authentication api is success
            //82782ewdhjdsjchjnscnsccn
};

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instaKey().applicationToken` will only work if `instaKey()` returns an object with an `applicationToken` property.  But your `instaKey` function doesn't return anything.

Furthermore, it relies on an asynchronous `Request.post` completing to obtain the `applicationToken`.  So `instaKey` would have to return a promise that is resolved with the value of `applicationToken`.

The general pattern for the fix is to `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...` and then call `resolve(applicationToken)` when it's available, and of course you'll need to either `await instaKey()` function or use `instaKey().then(key => { /* TODO: Use key here. */ })`.

Example:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Request.post(
        {
            headers: headers,
            url: `${BaseUrl}/oauth2/token/`,
            formData: {
                grant_type: `client_credentials`,
                client_id: clientId,
                client_secret: clientSecret
            },
        },
        (error, instaApplicationTokenResponse, instaApplicationTokenResBody) => {
            if (instaApplicationTokenResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("Authentication api is success");
                applicationToken = JSON.parse(instamojoApplicationTokenResBody).access_token;
                console.log(applicationToken);
                resolve(applicationToken)
            } else {
                console.error("Authentication api failed");
                reject();
            }
        });
});
```

And then you'd have to do something like this to call it:

```
createOrder: async (req, res) => {

    console.log("Key is ");
    let key = await instaKey();
    console.log(key);
};
```

Comment: Thanks that helped to clear my concept. What is the ... in this ? instaKey().then(key => ...)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I meant it as a placeholder for the rest of your code.  e.g.:  `instaKey().then(key => /*...*/)`  "Do something with `key` here".  I have edited for clarity.